# Python Cant find attribute in module and strange behavior

Tags: python, module, attributes, sublimetext

Ok lets say I have 3 files, we will call them a,b,c. I am using sublime to run and build these scripts.

```
a imports and uses method from b
b imports and uses method from c
c imports and uses method from a
```

With ctrl+b Sublime 2 will build and run my code.

Build with **a** tab active ==>

```
Error: module b has no attribute 'x'
```

Build with **b** tab active ==>

```
Error: Module c has no attribute 'y'
```

Build with **c** tab active ==>

```
Success
```

Is this an issue with Sublime specific or a problem with my code.

Comment: What's the exact code in question?

Comment: Circular imports are not in principle a problem. You can have two (or more) modules import each other and everything is hunky dory. It must be what happens in the module that's the problem... (I've never heard of Sublime but a code editor shouldn't be able to screw up python.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a tricky corner case in Python when doing circular imports. If you use the "import ..." form of the import statement, like this:

```
# a.py
import b
def method_a():
    print "Method A called"
def call_b_from_a():
    b.method_b()
```

```
# b.py
import c
def method_b():
    print "Method B called"
def call_c_from_b():
    c.method_c()
```

```
# c.py
import a
def method_c():
    print "Method C called"
def call_a_from_c():
    a.method_a()
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
>>> import a
>>> a.call_b_from_a()
Method B called
```

and similarly for b and c; in short, everything just works. However, if you use the "from ... import ..." form of the import statement, like this:

```
# a.py
from b import method_b
def method_a():
    print "Method A called"
def call_b_from_a():
    method_b()
```

```
# b.py
from c import method_c
def method_b():
    print "Method B called"
def call_c_from_b():
    method_c()
```

```
# c.py
from a import method_a
def method_c():
    print "Method C called"
def call_a_from_c():
    method_a()
```

Then you get errors like this:

```
>>> import a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    from b import method_b
  File "b.py", line 2, in <module>
    from c import method_c
      File "c.py", line 2, in <module>
    from a import method_a
ImportError: cannot import name method_a
```

In short, circular imports can be used, but they do pose some corner cases. Without actually seeing your code, I would guess it's probably something related to that.

For future reference, you'll almost always get better answers if you post the actual code you're using.